# Plotting different versions of the same graph multiple times

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to modify the parameters of a function and then plot it in a loop, and I having problems with that. The problem is that I need labels and different colors for each plot

Something like:

```
hold on

for n = N

for t = Time_inv

    error = func(n, t);
    error_array_2(i) = error;
    i = i + 1;

end
    plot (Time_inv, error_array_2);
    i = 1;
end
```

I am new to Matlab, but experienced with other languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple lines on one plot, use `hold all` and maybe a [legend](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html).

```
figure
hold all
plot(rand(1,10))
plot(rand(1,10))
plot(rand(1,10))
legend('label 1', 'label 2', 'label 3')
```

For multiple plots in one figure, use [subplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html).

```
figure
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(rand(1,10))
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(rand(1,10))
```

For plots in different figures, use [figure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html).

```
figure
plot(rand(1,10))
figure
plot(rand(1,10))
```

Comment: It is a requirement to have all the plots on 1 window, since the graphs need to be compared

Answer (score 0):

To have different colors and labels for each graph you could create a color map and a cell array of labels:

```
h = zeros(1, length(N))
name = cell(1, length(N))

cm = hsv(length(N));
for n = N
    name{n} = ['condition ' num2str(n)];
    i = 1
    for t = Time_inv
        error = func(n, t);
        error_array_2(i) = error;
        i = i + 1;
    end
    h(n) = plot (Time_inv, error_array_2, 'color', cm(n,:));
    hold on    
end

legend(h, name);
```

Since you point out that you are new to matlab, i will just mention that you propably don't need the iterator `i` as functions generally works on matrices. Therefore your script can be shortened (excerpt):

```
for n = N
    ...
    error_array_2 = func(n, Time_inv);
    ... 
end
```